# How can I customize Password Confirm View when received Email Django Rest Auth

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, django-urls, django-rest-auth

I am implementing Password reset by using django Rest Auth, two thing I requires when request hits from reactjs frontend I want the email to be customize I want to use password_reset_email.html template.Firstly I used simple PasswordResetView and I got the email but it sends me to native Rest UI PasswordConfirmView.

I want,when User hit request it should use my templates which are, password_reset.html,password_reset_confirm.html,password_reset_done.html... which we make in our templates/appname directory
my try:

**urls.py:**

```
   urlpatterns=[
url(
    r'^rest-auth/password/reset/$',
    PasswordResetView.as_view(),
    name='password_reset',
),
url(
    r'^rest-auth/password/reset/confirm/'
    r'(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
    PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(),
    name='password_reset_confirm'),
    ]
```

**authsystem/templates:**

password_reset_confirm.html:

```
          <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <title>Title</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        {% if validlink %}
           <h3>Change password</h3>
              <form method="post">
               {% csrf_token %}
              {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Change password</button>
</form>
   {% else %}
    <p>
  The password reset link was invalid, possibly because it has already been used.
  Please request a new password reset.
</p>
 {% endif %}
</body>
 </html>
```

I know the above approach is less but I want the direction how can I make it work I don't want to use rest auth built-in UI, when request hits from react side,How can I use templates when the email is sent,when I click on link in email I want to show my template, token and uid should pass from templates,I have all the templates ready but don't know how to use with Django Rest Auth.

Comment: This isn't a REST view (API) it's just a normal view from the **allauth** package, so you shouldn't have to change any URLs ( if you did `url(r'^account/', include('allauth.urls')),` in your main urls). Just override the template used by **allauth** by putting the template inside an **account** directory inside your **templates** directory. Also I think the template name is incorrect, it should be **authsystem/templates/account/password_reset_from_key.html**

Answer (score 3):

In general, if you want to override templates from a package, make sure you check first the path of template used in the view. E.g. in the rest-auth package (if you didn't install allauth), password reset is handled by the default Django `PasswordResetConfirmView` (django.contrib.auth.views), which uses the template **'registration/password_reset_confirm.html'**, which for some reason resides in **django/contrib/admin/templates/registration**.

So the way templates are loaded, if in any of your apps, you have this template, it'll be loaded before the one from Django. Just create **authsystem/templates/registration/password_reset_confirm.html** and that's the one that will be used instead of the default one inside django/contrib/admin.

If you're using allauth, then the view is `PasswordResetFromKeyView` (allauth.account.views) and the corresponding template **account/password_reset_from_key.html**. Therefore, creating this template in **authsystem/templates/account/password_reset_from_key.html** will override the one from allauth.

Comment: I have removed all auth and just remain rest auth, i have overrided the password_reset_email.html template, but when I click on the link in email the native ui comes of django rest not mine custom authsystem/Templates/registration/password_reset_confirm.html

Comment: The link looks like :     http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/rest-auth/password/reset/confirm/MQ/598-d9cb0514b9a933cf0fd1/

Comment: I assume `authsystem` is an app in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Thank you for your response somehow I managed to make it work I overrided accounts template and then make some changes in serializer.

Comment: Same problem here, can not get Django (using rest-auth, not all-auth) to actually serve my custom template for the password change view (I get the DRF auto-generated OPTIONS-based view only when I direct the web-browser to the link in the email). It doesn't help that this is all magical, and that the sub-apps use each other's views and templates... :/

Comment: Actually, the GET to the link in the email returns 405 Method Not Allowed so it's not even attempting to get the template :(

Comment: Ok - as I discovered, when you use rest-auth, these templates are not used at all. The django-rest-auth views for the password confirms are purely POST-based, as they refer only to a REST api. You're on your own with the front-end. To use the templates, the confirm views inside django contrib auth have to be used instead.